# Playwright Test Library: How to verify whether two nodes are equal

Tags: playwright

I am trying to traverse from child element to parent element and verify whether the **child** and **parent nodes** are equal. I had used evaluate function which is throwing some exception.

I am not able to find the exact syntax. Below is the code.

```
      console.log("Parent Element "+ parent);
       let c1 = await page.locator(`${childEle} ${parent}`, {hasText: txt}).first().evaluate(node => node);
       console.log("c1 "+ c1);
       let p1 = await page.locator(parentEle).first().evaluate(node => node);
       await page.evaluate(
           ([c1, p1]) => p1.isEqualNode(c1),
           [c1, p1]);
```

output is:

[image]

Basically, it clicks on the element which matches the text within the element. Clicking the element with the text with the top-down and bottom-up approach.

Comment: What exception is it throwing? Please share a runnable [mcve] and provide [context for why you need to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to verify two nodes are equal. Below is the code

```
console.log("Parent Element "+ parent);
        let c1 = await page.locator(`${childEle} ${parent}`).first().evaluateHandle(node => node);
        let p1 = await page.locator(parentEle).first().evaluateHandle(node => node);
        const inpuValue =  await page.evaluateHandle(
           ([c1, p1]) => c1.parentNode.isEqualNode(p1.parentNode), 
           [c1, p1]);
       console.log("inputValue "+ inpuValue);
```

I have used **evaluateHandle** instead of **evaluate** function.

[image]